# Drawing a blank

Tags: onion-routing

I don't use Tor that often, but how do I access .onion sites. I am completely lost - I remember my name, password, and pin - but how to get there? HELP!

Comment: Tor itself doesn’t have names, passwords, or PINs. To access an onion site, just open the Tor Browser and type in the onion address. You will need to find the onion address for the site you’re trying to get to. The address may have changed since the last time you visited it.

Comment: @Steve you should really start posting some of your comments as answers. Like this one

Answer (score 2):

To quote Steve's comment, which is actually a good answer:

Tor itself doesn’t have names, passwords, or PINs. To access an onion site, just open the Tor Browser and type in the onion address. You will need to find the onion address for the site you’re trying to get to. The address may have changed since the last time you visited it.